# Eliminate Views Entity Reference Duplicates. I have some titles the same on purpose

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a view with an entity reference pulling in what I need from a content type. There are, on purpose, titles that are the same.

Is there a way to compare what is output and then only show one of the titles?

I am showing these in a select list.

This is not duplicates, as they are separate entries... so using the Query Settings > Distinct isn't the correct solution in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hook_views_pre_render to get at the results array before it is output to the screen.

e.g.

```
function my_module_views_pre_render($view) {
  if ($view->name == 'the machine name of the view') {
    foreach ($view->result as $result) {
      // do some kind of comparison and de-duplification
    }
  }
}
```